# JavaFX Hover Pane over Pane

Tags: java, layout, javafx, hover

I am having a Border Pane with center Pane - VBox. 
The VBox contains a GridPane and a VBox pane.

The VBox (the one that is inside the VBox) is initially set as invisible.

What I want to do is if an element of the GridPane i.e grid[x][y] is hovered to change the state of the VBox as visible.

This is the code I use. temporary is the Vbox

```
 grid_map[19][19].hoverProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<?
 extends    Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean show) -> {
        if (show) {
            temporary.setLayoutX( grid_map[19][19].getLayoutX()); // this is not really working

            temporary.setVisible(true);
        } else {
              temporary.setVisible(false);
        //      grid_map[19][19].get
        }

    });
```

It is working, but it displays the VBox on the bottom side of the grid. What I want to do is to get the coordinates of the hovered element and to display the VBox over that element or on its left or right side. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell the "outer" `Vbox` not to position the temporary vbox for you:

```
temporary.setManaged(false);
```

Then setting the `layoutX` and `layoutY` as you are currently doing should work.

You may need to resize the temporary vbox, which looks like this:

```
grid_map[19][19].hoverProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, show) -> {
    if (show) {

         double x = grid_map[19][19].getLayoutX();
         double y = grid_map[19][19].getLayoutY();
         double w = temporary.prefWidth(-1);
         double h = temporary.prefHeight(w);
         temporary.resizeRelocate(x, y, w, h);
         temporary.setVisible(true);
    } else {
          temporary.setVisible(false);
    }

});
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed !